# MVC Oauth2 Accessing Google Analytics

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-analytics, oauth-2.0, google-analytics-api

I've setup my asp.net MVC website to allow login through Google:

In *App_Start\Startup.Auth.cs*

```
var googlePlusOptions = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google.GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = "someid",
            ClientSecret = "somesecret",
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie,
        };
        googlePlusOptions.Scope.Add("email");
        googlePlusOptions.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly");

        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(googlePlusOptions);
```

I thought I would see an Authorization code in the claims list, but there is nothing there.  Where do I get the Authorization code?  Any tutorials or help would be greatly appreciated, I'm new with MVC, OAuth, and Google APIs and feel a bit over my head.